# Website doesn't appear In first 20 list of links in a Google Search

Tags: wordpress

I have recently completed one website and am now working on SEO for same, in order to get listed in first 20 links of Google search.
Basically our website is on car rent services in Goa, India.

I completed with following things in SEO

1. Verified my website in Search console
2. Uploaded the .html file on server
3. Also uploaded robots.txt.
4. Generated site map and uploaded the same on server
5. Pages submitted for indexing ....in fetch as Google some pages show status as complete and partial
6. Key words added to pages using plugin.

All the above has been done but still our website is not getting listed in first 20 of Google search.

Pages submitted for indexing but still count shows 0.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Verifying website or adding robots.txt doesnt guaranty your website to be listed in top search results. It all depends on website traffic , SEO etc.. Google on how to SEO for help.

Comment: SEO does not happen in one day. It is process that takes time.

Answer (score 1):

SEO is a slow and steady process; naturally it will take time to achieve the top position in search result.

**Things you should do;**

1) Add meta title and description to each page based on the keywords

2) Include keywords in URL of the page

3) Create a webmaster tool and use fetch page option to get listed in search engines (Example: Google webmaster is must needed)

4) Create brand pages in social media sites and interlink with website

5) submit your website to dmoz.org

https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo --> Useful guide for you

Answer (score -1):

Check out Google's Webmaster Guidelines: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769

> Following these guidelines will help Google find, index, and rank your site.